# How to prove linearity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a third-order differential equation, of the form $y''' + f(t,y,y',y'') = 0.$ that admits solution:
$$Y(t) = y(t) + C_1 f_1(t) + C_2 f_2(t) + C_3 f_3(t)$$
where $y(t)$ is a particular solution, and  $f_1(t), f_2(t), f_3(t)$ are linearly independent functions, then
**How to prove that the differential equation is linear?**,
that is I want to prove that $$f(t,y,y',y'') = A(t) y'' + B(t) y' + C(t) y + D(t)$$

Comment: i think this question lacks context. I fail to understand what is what.

Comment: OK. Let say, we are considering differential equation of form:
$y''' + f(t,y,y',y'') = 0.$
All functions $Y(t)$ satisfy the DE.
Now I want to prove that $f(t,y,y',y'') = A(t) y'' + B(t) y' + C(t) y + D(t)$

Comment: Assume the equation is $z'''=F(t,z,z',z'')$. Write the identity $Y'''=F(t,Y,Y',Y'')$, which holds for all $C_1,C_2,C_3$ and take second derivatives with respect to $C_1,C_2,C_3$. Then you get an homogeneous linear system of equations involving the second derivatives of $F$ and derivatives of $f_1,f_2,f_3$. See if using that the Wronskian of $f_1,f_2,f_3$ is non-zero you can deduce that the second derivatives of $F$ are zero.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$\begin{cases}Y(t)- y(t) = C_1 f_1(t) + C_2 f_2(t) + C_3 f_3(t)\\
Y'(t)- y'(t) = C_1 f_1'(t) + C_2 f_2'(t) + C_3 f_3'(t)\\
Y''(t)- y''(t) = C_1 f_1''(t) + C_2 f_2''(t) + C_3 f_3''(t)\\
Y'''(t)- y'''(t) = C_1 f_1'''(t) + C_2 f_2'''(t) + C_3 f_3'''(t).\end{cases}$$

Now you can express that this system has nontrivial solutions for $C$ by the condition

$$\Delta=0$$ which can be developed as

$$(Y(t)- y(t))M_0(t)+(Y'(t)- y'(t))M_1(t)+(Y''(t)- y''(t))M_2(t)+(Y'''(t)- y'''(t))M_2(t)=0$$ (where $M_k$ are minors built on the RHS), a linear ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Take the differential equation :

$$(y^{(3)})^2=0 $$

Then the solutions to this equation are exactly the polynomials of degree $\leq 2$. Then set $f_1(t):=1$, $f_2(t):=t$ and $f_3(t):=t^2$. And $y(t)=0$ is a solution. Hence all the solutions of my equation are of the form :

$$Y(t)=y(t)+C_1f_1(t)+C_2f_2(t)+C_3f_3(t) $$

With $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ being linearly independant.

However I wouldn't say that the differential equation is linear (because of the square...). Nevertheless the set of solution is a vector space.

Comment: Nah. Your equation is not solved for the highest derrivative :)
If you solve it, it will be $y^{(3)} = 0$.

Comment: @user12355 so my answer fails to meet the condition "solved for the highest derivative". Maybe you could explain formally this condition (by editing your answer).

Comment: OK, it means that we deal with differential equation of form:
$y''' + f(t,y,y',y'') = 0.$

Answer (score -2):

Assume you have two solutions, prove that their sum is a solution, proceed with the other requirements of linearity.

Comment: Does this prove that the *equation* is linear ?